# Convert UTF-8 string to readable string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 string like:

`a= "for ccps â€˜the way forwardâ€™"`

And want to convert to `for CCPs ‘the way forward’`

I tried code like:

`CGI.escape a`

Comment: What does `p a.encoding` show?

Comment: shows `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Comment: Are you looking to just change the encoding, or are you looking to parse the string as well?  Because changing from "ccp" to "CCP" is more than just converting the format...

Comment: Just change the encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

```
a= "for ccps â€˜the way forwardâ€™"
a.encode("cp1252").force_encoding("utf-8")
```